# Securing API calls GAE endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm writing a mobile app as a thin client that fetch data from the a server. I am using Google app engine to host my backend and using all the services they offer. I am using endpoints to expose for my API. I found [this tutorial](http://rominirani.com/2014/02/14/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-5/) to secure my API. I test from the api explorer as everything worked fine. if I am not using Oauth 2 I cannot use the API. However, when I investigate the HTTP header, I don't find the "authorization: bearer" line, that would be holding the one time token that will be used to authenticate and authorize the API call. Now i'm doubting I did not something correct, because normally I have to see this line. There is a screenshot of my call with request showing that it was executed although there is not the line I pointed earlier. There is also pieces of my code which is generated by Android studio partially.

```
    @ApiMethod(
        name = "get",
        path = "offer/{id}",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public Offer get(@Named("id") long id, User user) throws NotFoundException, UnauthorizedException {

    if (user == null) throw new UnauthorizedException("User is Not Valid");

    logger.info("Getting Offer with ID: " + id);
    Offer offer = ofy().load().type(Offer.class).id(id).now();
    if (offer == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException("Could not find Offer with ID: " + id);
    }
    return offer;
}
```

Any clue about why the line containing the token is missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to log user.getUserId(), user.getNickname(), and user.getEmail() to see what's going on.

I think there are cookies and other means that auth info is stored as I rarely have to login twice to a website.